# How do I close the download pop in chrome browser when downloading PDF

Tags: java, pdf, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using java selenium to automate my application.I am downloading PDF and parsing.There are multiple test cases with PDF in my application. So once i download first PDF the chrome show a pop at the bottom of browser that file is downloaded with file name so next time when i try to download the second PDF the Download button is below this pop and not able to click on download option.
Used isDisplayed method to check status which return false and isEnabled returns true.Tried execution of the PDF testcase in another window it is not working either. Please refer the image for the POP.

Thanks in advance.

[image: The pop-up I am talking about]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks your Found the solution .I am using Robot class to press Control key and "J"(using Ctrl+J),this open my download files in new tab.After I used windowsHandle to close the new window and navigate back to original window.

//your code to download file,after downloading file use below code

Below is my code for

```
enter code here

         Robot bot =new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
         bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J);
         bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J);
        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
      for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

    }
```

Comment: Hi Amol, Will it work in Headless mode? Robot class 's keyPress?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no way to close download panel on Chrome using Selenium/WebDriver. There may be some other solutions for you to consider. For example:

1. Move to element you want to locate using Action chains `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions`

2. Download in a new tab, then close the tab after downloading then the original tab does not have the download bar. 

3. Open chrome downloads page(using Ctrl+J), then close it and go back to your main page and it does not have the download bar.

There may be other solutions available for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a tool that can control UI objects. One of them, a freeware, is Auto-It. It can identify the download\upload window of the browser, control it, and close it. You can write you script, build it - and from your code in Java - call it when the download\upload window is opened.